# Event Hub Consumer not receiving events

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

I have a python receiver script which processes the events i.e on blob create an event is triggered and the data is loaded to database.

When I run the script locally and upload a blob file,  my receiver script runs fine and the data is extracted.

But when the blob is uploaded to the same container by a different service I do not see any events coming through?

I am new to Event hubs so not sure where the problem is..

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the solution you are using for blob triggered events? Event Grid?

Comment: Yes it's event grid

Comment: Can you check Event Hubs metrics and confirm events ingested for both cases? See if this is a producer or a consumer issue.

Comment: I've checked the producer creating blobs and Event hub metrics show events ingested both manually and through a process. But the events are ingesting into database only when manually uploaded but not via the process (.net App). Not sure where the problem is.